# Angle between matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the problem from my homework:

> If $A$ is antisymmetric matrix, and $S$ is symmetric matrix where $A,S \in M_n (\mathbb{R})$, determine the angle between them according to the inner product defined as $(A,B)=\text{tr}(AB^T)$.

I have tried calculating the angle between two pairs of concrete matrices from space $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, and the angles don't turn out to be the same. Am I doing something wrong? If it's even possible, how to determine that angle? Thanks.

Comment: A guess that angle is defined by $(A,B) = ||A||\, ||B|| \cos \alpha$. So where is the problem?

Comment: I just thought that the angle should turn out to be the same for any pair of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: As $A$ is antisymmetric, $S$ symmetric, we have 
$$ SA^t = -SA, \quad AS^t = AS $$
Hence
$$\def\tr{\mathop{\rm tr}}\tr(SA^t) = -\tr(SA) = -\tr(AS) = -\tr(AS^t) $$

Answer (score 0):

The trace verifies the [property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Trace_of_a_product) $tr(A B^T)=tr(B A^T)$, so$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{tr(A B^T)}{\sqrt{tr(A A^T)tr(B B^T)}}=\frac{tr(B A^T)}{\sqrt{tr(A A^T)tr(B B^T)}}$$