# Angle between matrices, but with determinants and matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The dot product of two vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ can be in terms of matrix multiplication and in terms of lengths and angles:

$$\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{v} = |\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|\cos{\theta} $$

Let's say I *literally* replace $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ with matrices $A$ and $B$:

$$A \cdot B = A^TB = |A||B|\cos{Θ} $$

Rearranging, we get:
$$Θ = \arccos \frac{A^TB}{|A||B|} \ \dot = \ \arccos \frac{A^TB}{\det A \det B}$$

Does this concept of $Θ$ exist somewhere? Perhaps as some sort of "angle" between matrices $A$ and $B$?

Things I've already thought of:

1. If you use the Taylor series definitions of $\cos$ or $\arccos$, and let $Θ$ be a matrix, I believe computing $Θ$ is fairly easy (but hard for the computer maybe).
2. The concept of an "angle" between matrices exists [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414579/angle-between-matrices) [(2)](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/calculating-angles-between-matrices.513806/) if we are redefining "$| \ |$" as some norm, but here, I abuse notation and redefine "$| \ |$" as the determinant, which is not a norm.

Comment: You have a type error. $A^TB/{\rm det}A{\rm det}B$ is a matrix, but $\arccos$ expects a scalar. EDIT: Well, I suppose there are ways of expanding it to accept matrices. You're basically arccos-ing the eigenvalues.

Comment: Perhaps you should use the trace inner product. It essentially treats the matrix as a vector.

Comment: In any case, my suspicion is that the quantity doesn't have nice properties or any nice interpretation (though I don't know how one would prove that).

Comment: replacing with determinants sounds not useful IMO. Even if $B=I$, the quantity $A/\det A$ scales like $\lambda^{-n+1}$, when you replace $A$ with $\lambda A$. So the "angle" between $\lambda A$ and $I$ can't be real (as in the eigenvalues, as Akiva said) for sufficiently small $\lambda$

Comment: Note that throwing in determinants means that you allow only nonsingular (square) matrices.